# Two different slide designs in a single PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, slideshow

Is it even possible to do that? If so, what's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: also, which version of powerpoint are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to change the design of a particular slide:

1. Select the slide you wish to modify by clicking on it in the Slides view.
2. Select the Format menu > Slide Design.
3. Choose the design you would like to use from the task pane by selecting the drop down arrow that appears when you hover your mouse over the preview slide.
4. Select Apply to Selected Slides.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it on Powerpoint 2010. If you right click the theme you should be able to apply it to the selected slides instead of all of them.

in 2003 if you are looking at the slide designs an arrow should pop up on the left side of the design you have hilighted. click that and it should give you the same option.

Comment: I guess there is no way of achieving this in Microsoft Powerpoint 2003?

Comment: no. i just don't have 2003 to test it. but one of my friends does. give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple solution (if printing to paper or transparencies)

Assuming your presentation is Portrait, but you have one slide you want in Landscape (11" wide x 8.5" tall):

1. Ensure "View" is set to "Normal."
2. Create your Landscape slide putting objects beyond the page edges.  For an edge guide, you can make an 11" wide x 8.5" tall box and send it to the back. Then create your slide within the box edges.
3. When done, delete the guide box only and save the file (don't close).
4. Select all the objects on the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) and combine into a single group.
5. Rotate the entire group 90 degrees counter-clockwise and center on page.
6. Save your file.

#### If using a computer and projector for slide show

- When you get to the Landscape slide, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to point the page "top" (which is the Landscape slide's right edge) to the right.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> to point page top back up.
- If using multiple monitors, the screen displaying the mouse cursor is the one that will rotate.

#### Option to create guide box

1. Change presentation orientation to Landscape. Some pages/images will deform but will return to normal when restored to Portrait.
2. Create Landscape slide and save the file (don't close, though).
3. Group together all items on the page and save your file.
4. Cut the group from the page.
5. Restore presentation orientation to Portrait.
6. Paste the group onto the page.
7. Rotate the group 90 degrees counter-clockwise and center on page.
8. Save your file.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, this may not be what the OP had in mind.  For some future readers, though, it might be useful for their needs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using PPT 2010, and it appears that you can add multiple sections like you can in Word.  Just right click between two slides in the Slide Sorter view, then add section.  This is very convenient.

Comment: Adding a new section does not allow you to use multiple slide designs. At least not in PPT 2013. Can you confirm the steps to enable multiple slide designs?

Answer (score -1):

I did it a few seconds ago! 
You don't have to click on the master slides because it didn't work for me. 
I tried clicking on the other icons and found out one thing:

1. click on view
2. click on slide sorter (you will get all the slides placed together)
3. then right click on (format background) on the slide you wish to change. 
   you will get a box on your right side to check colrs, size, etc.

Hope it works for you ;)

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.